# Database name 'mydb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb. Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server, excel, bulk-insert

I'm trying to insert data from an **xlsx** file into my temporal table. I've also tried with a real table, but it throws me the following error:

> (0 rows affected)

I'm pretty sure my error is in the **bulk insert** part, because when I run just that part it throws me the same error.

This is the statement I am using to insert the data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stats_ddl') is not null DROP TABLE #stats_ddl 
GO
CREATE TABLE #stats_ddl ([Fecha] varchar(50),
[Descripción] varchar(max),
[Depósitos] varchar(50),
[Retiros] varchar(50),
[Saldo] varchar(50));
Go 

bulk insert mydb.dbo.#stats_ddl
from 'C:\some\where\myfile\is\file.xlsx'
with (          firstrow = 14,                    
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

I am receiving this error:

> Database name 'mydb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.

What issues am I facing?

Comment: [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) are *not* the same as [temporary tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables).  Do you mean "temporal" or "temporary"?

Comment: Try testing your field and row terminators. Like open in Notepad++ and turn on all chars and verify that you are actually having tabs and CR&LF for your terminators.

Comment: It looks strange to import a .xlsx file with settings for a TSV.

Comment: That message “Database name 'mydb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.” is a notice/warning, not an error. You likely have an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify a database name, or schema name, when using a #temporary table.

Remove the `#` from the name of the stats_ddl table, and you'll see it works.

If you want to insert the rows into a temporary table, then remove the reference to the database name:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#stats_ddl') is not null DROP TABLE #stats_ddl 
GO
CREATE TABLE #stats_ddl ([Fecha] varchar(50),
[Descripción] varchar(max),
[Depósitos] varchar(50),
[Retiros] varchar(50),
[Saldo] varchar(50));
Go 

bulk insert #stats_ddl
from 'C:\some\where\myfile\is\file.xlsx'
with (          firstrow = 14,                    
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Comment: As noted in comments on the question, you've provided field and row terminators that match up to a tab-separated values file. To upload it that way, you need to save the Excel file as a tab-delimited text file. To use the Excel file directly, you need to use something like `OPENDATASOURCE` or `OPENROWSET` (see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5942b056-7985-4cc0-9628-6dcbc6f6bda1/bulk-insert-for-loading-xls-excel-files?forum=transactsql) for examples.